# Meaning of "no scratch no snatch"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, slang

I'm trying to understand all the lyrics of [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WnLmF_ZF_4). At [2:20](https://youtu.be/9WnLmF_ZF_4?t=2m20s), the song goes "but she says no scratch no snatch". I understand the meaning of these words separately, but I don't get the meaning of the expression.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"She" is a prostitute.

This usage of [*scratch*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scratch) is slang for *money*. Here, [*snatch*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/snatch) is slang for a woman's genitals. Metaphorically, it stands for sex. In other words, she is saying

> No money, no sex

meaning *if you don't have money, you will not get sex*. However, the lyrics might be telling a different story.

Comment: "No Money, No Honey" Is a non hip-hop and less sleazy way to say the same thing!